# restricting users to create new article in blog gives " undefined method `is_admin?' for nil:NilClass" in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, admin

I am implementing blog app in ruby on rails where I want to restrict normal user( only admin can create) from creating new articles. For this purpose, I have put befor_filter in articles_controller.rb file which is following. I have hided create button from user in UI but still normal user can create new article by typing in address bar of browser.By using below code, normal user can not go on new article page but it gives me "undefined method `is_admin? when i type in address bar. For more info, I have implemented devise for user authentication.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_user_admin, only: [:new, :create]

  def is_user_admin
    unless  current_user.is_admin?
      :root 
      return false
    end
  end
end 



class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_user_admin, only: [:new, :create]

  def is_user_admin
    unless  current_user.is_admin?
      :root 
      return false
    end
  end

    def index
        @articles = Article.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.new(params[:article])
      @article.user_id = current_user.id
      @article.save
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end

    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.destroy
      redirect_to action:  'index'  
    end

    def edit
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
      flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
     end
end
```

applicaiton_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
      def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
         if current_user.is_admin?
             dashboard_index_path
         else
             :root
         end
      end

end
```

Basically, I want to restrict normal user (other than admin) to create , update or delete articles either from UI(this is done) or typing address in address bar.
I have no idea why i am getting this and what can i do to avoid this. Should i write above method in application_controller.rb file.

Comment: Can you show us the current_user method?

Comment: hi fmendez, current_user method is part devise. I have not created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propably want to redirect users to login so they can't access the action in your controller, if they're not admins. Hence, you could do something like this:

```
def is_user_admin
  redirect_to(action: :index) unless current_user.try(:is_admin?)
end
```

Comment: hi agis, i tried with your suggestion , it allows user to create article by typing in address bar though i did not give "“ undefined method `is_admin?' for nil:NilClass” error.

Comment: Have you tried the updated version? The users will be redirected to the index action if they are not admins. They shouldn't be able to access the action at all. Isn't that what you want? Btw you'd propably want to redirect them to a route like `login_path` instead of the action I used, but I used it just to demonstrate a working code for your case, since I don't know your routes.

Comment: hi agis. I want to enhance this functionality, when user tries to create, edit the article , he should get error  page like we get at github 404. How i can be implement this. any idea.

Comment: Well, that's another subject but.. you'd want to create a separate action for this and redirect them to that action instead of the `index` action as the code I've wrote does.

Answer (score 2):

Your `current_user` is nil apparently.

You should put `before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]` at the top of your controller in order to authenticate user.

Comment: hi adnam, when I put before_filter :authenticate_user! in articles_controller.rb file, it forces user to log in even to view the articles but i want to allow user to view but not create,delete and update the articles. Only admin can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that at least there is an user before checking for the permission. You can do that adding this code to every controller that requires an authentication:

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Doing this, you will always have a current user and hence will be able to check for its permission the way you pointed on your question.

Comment: hi rodrigo, i got solution by using def is_user_admin
  redirect_to(action: :index) unless current_user.try(:is_admin?)
end . thanks btw.